# INFA workflow fails when scheduler enabled

Tags: informatica

I am trying to run an Informatica workflow to check database table and write fetched data to a flat file on the server.

- source: database table
- target: flat file
- transformations: non

this wf runs fine when "run on demand" but I need to run this continuously so I tried with INFA scheduler to run it every 5 minutes. When the scheduler is enabled the workflow continuously fails. Kindly help with any ideas to run this on scheduler.

[image]

Comment: Could you please check in the source/target,mapping, session,workflow ? I think mapping isnt checked in when scheduled? Also are you using your user to schedule or some other user?

Comment: hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes I checked it was checked in properly and sorry I do not understand this part "Also are you using your user to schedule or some other user?"

Answer (score 0):

oops... sorted, this was my mistake. I have not checked in the Target I created for flat file. my bad. Thanks all